# AyncTask JSON from url

Tags: android, json, url

having a few problems with my application and unsure what is wrong. Basically the program will load on my android device and just sit there doing nothing, no error messages will be displayed in the console/logcat and the text on the textviews isnt changing just wondering if anyone has any insight thanks.

```
11-03 21:55:21.474: I/System.out(16741): execute
11-03 21:55:21.474: I/System.out(16741): started
11-03 21:55:21.524: D/libEGL(16741): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_tegra.so
11-03 21:55:21.544: D/libEGL(16741): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_tegra.so
11-03 21:55:21.554: D/libEGL(16741): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_tegra.so
11-03 21:55:21.584: D/OpenGLRenderer(16741): Enabling debug mode 0
```

Here is my JSON file from the url

```
{
"fruit": [
    {
        "type": "apple",
        "color": "green"
    },
    {
        "type": "orange",
        "color": "orange"
    },
    {
        "type": "banana",
        "color": "yellow"
    }
]
```

}

This is my first time trying to code for an android device and have no idea to why nothing is happening, the device has access to the url as I have loaded it from the browser and it seems to load fine.

```
package com.example.fruitjson;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

static String url = "http://192.168.0.14/fruitlist.json";
String TAG_FRUIT = "fruit";
String TAG_TYPE = "type";
String TAG_COLOR = "color";

JSONArray fruit = null;
JSONObject json = null;
InputStream is = null;
JSONObject result = null;
String jsonString = "";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    System.out.println("execute");
    new MyAsyncTask().execute();
    System.out.println("started");
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject> {
    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            jsonString = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }
        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            result = new JSONObject(jsonString);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }
        // return JSON String
        return result;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // get text views, loop out strings
        System.out.println("getting text views");
        TextView t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        TextView t2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        System.out.println(t1.getText());
        System.out.println(t2.getText());
        System.out.println("success");
        try {
            fruit = json.getJSONArray(TAG_FRUIT);
            for (int i = 0; i < fruit.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jObj = fruit.getJSONObject(i);
                String type = jObj.getString(TAG_TYPE);
                String color = jObj.getString(TAG_COLOR);

                t1.setText(type);
                t2.setText(color);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
}
```

Comment: have u checked for exceptions or tried to print them in catch block do that to see where u getting probelm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't using the correct onPostExecute method. You need to override the method:

```
@Override 
protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) { ... }
```